# Nginx: How to serve different urls with different settings from one file?

Tags: nginx, mime-type

I have thousands of text files named like `ABC`. I'd like to access those files from different URL:
- if it is `ABC` or `ABC.txt` I'd like to add `default_type text/plain` and serve that file
- if it is `ABC.html` I'd like to add `default_type text/html` and serve that file
(so that I have two different versions of the same file).

Is it possible to do that in nginx? The fact that one url could only be matched with one `location` directive causes me trouble in finding a "clean" way.

Comment: I've modified the question to clarify that it should match a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to create a separate location for each file extension and use a internal redirect.
It'll be something like that:

```
location /ABC.txt {
  add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  rewrite /ABC last;
}
location /ABC.html {
  add_header Content-Type text/html;
  rewrite /ABC last;
}
location /ABC {
  alias /var/www/ABC.txt
}
```

I don't promise it'll work because I have not tested it on a real nginx.

Comment: I could modify your settings to match a pattern with regular expression. However the tricky part is there is no content-type header if it is accessed without extension, and nginx uses "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".

Comment: To add a content type even when file is accessed without extension just add one more location with add_header parameter.

Comment: I tested and it did not work. I always get the text/plain, with or without .html http://dev.jcisio.com/paste/Nfe74Cxf

Answer (score 1):

nginx processes the suggested mimetype based on the URI. I tried the following combination and it works:

```
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;

    default_type text/plain;

    location = /abc.txt {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/www/abc;
    }

    location /abc.html {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/www/abc;
    }
```